# VBA, Looping through Pivot Values to filter pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through values in my pivot table and select two of them.

`filter` is my first value, `filtertwo` is my second, How can I add `filtertwo` to the `If` statement so both values are included in the filtering.

I need to be able to do two `Vartypes` here, I am confused on how to add that to that statement.

```
For Each pivItem In periodField.PivotItems
    v = pivItem.Value
    Debug.Print v
    If VarType(v) = VarType(Filter) Then
        pivItem.Visible = (v = Filter)
    End If
Next pivItem
```

ive tried:

```
        If VarType(v) = VarType(Filter) or VarType(FilterTwo) Then
            pivItem.Visible = (v = Filter)
            pivItem.Visible = (v = Filtertwo)
```